# akka slick alternative to anorm SQL(...).on(params)

Tags: slick, akka-stream, anorm

I am doing as follows with anorm:

```
val name = "john"
val age = 30
val params: Seq[NamedParameter] = List(NamedParameter("name", name), NamedParameter("age", age))
SQL"insert into person (name, age) values ({name}, {age})".on(params:_*)).executeUpdate()
```

I am aware it could be simpler as follows:

```
SQL"insert into person (name, age) values ($name, $age)".executeUpdate()
```

However, I have a dynamic list of paramters, so I need to use the first option.

I am now using akka streams and I replaced anorm by slick, because slick has a akka streams connector.
I use slicks with plain sql queries, instead of case classes.

The second option works well:

```
sqlu"insert into person (name, age) values ($name, $age)"
```

but I don't see how to use the fist option as in anorm: `SQL(...).on(params:_*)`

any idea?

Comment: The question is not very clear. Do you want to keep the use of NamedParameter with Slick? Don't you have a Person case class? And is there a good reason to use plain sql queries?

Comment: yes, I want to use the slick version of NamedParameter. I don't have a Person case class. I need to insert data into a table, and I don't know in advance what are the number of columns and column names.